# Under what conditions on $A$ and $v$ is the size of the sumset $v \cdot A + A$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ equal or close to $|A|^2$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, finite-groups, finite-fields, additive-combinatorics

Let $p$ be a prime, let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{F}_p$, and let $v \in \mathbb{F}_p \setminus \{0\}$.

Under what conditions is $|v \cdot A + A|$ (that is, $|\{ va + b : a \in A,\ b \in A \}|$) equal to or close to $|A|^2$?

I'm particularly interested in the case where $A = [0, 2^k)$, $p > 2^{2k}$, and $v$ is an element of multiplicative order $3$ in $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ (so typically close to $p$ in bit length).

### Progress so far

Obviously, if $A = [0, 2^k)$, $p > 2^{2k}$, and $v$ were instead equal to $2^k$, then $|v \cdot A + A|$ would trivially be equal to $|A|^2$. And if $v$ were a random element of $\mathbb{F}_p$, heuristically I think we'd expect $|v \cdot A + A| \approx |A|^2$. The actual problem is nontrivial because the length of $v$ is within $k$ bits of $p$, so $v \cdot A$ "wraps around", potentially leading to multiple ways of obtaining the same element.

Cauchy–Davenport says that $|v \cdot A + A| > 2|A| - 1$, but that is not helpful.

One approach is to try to determine whether $v \cdot A$ has a nonempty intersection with $(-2^k, 2^k)$; if that intersection is empty then there cannot be two ways to obtain an element, and so we will have $|v \cdot A + A| = |A|^2$.

It's not too hard to express this as an instance of a subset sum decision problem (either over $\mathbb{F}_p$ or over the integers). However, for the sizes of problem I'm interested in ($p \approx 2^{256}$ and $k \approx 64$), that would be infeasible to solve using any subset sum algorithms I'm aware of. It's always possible there's a more efficient method for this particular case, of course.

I read the chapter on sum set estimates in Tao and Vu's [Additive Combinatorics](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/additive-combinatorics/), and it doesn't seem to be discussed there.

### Extension

I'm also interested in finding conditions under which $|v^2 \cdot A + v \cdot A + A|$ is equal to or close to $|A|^3$ when $p > 2^{3k}$.

Comment: Note that if $va+b = vc+d$ (with $a \ne c$) we would have $v = (d-b)/(a-c)$.  Thus if $B = A - A$, the number of $v$ for which $|vA+A| < |A|^2$ is at most $(|B|-1)^2$.

Comment: See Lemma 2.50 in Tao and Vu for when equality holds. Apply this to your example, the question is when is $x \in I/I$, where $I$ is an interval centered at the origin. For this problem, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.0120